# Can't read input file when compressed as a jar

Tags: java

I am trying to run a jar file in terminal when I get this error:

[image]

I can run this file fine in my IDE, but when I export the project as a jar, it cannot find the file. Here is the code that the error points to:

```
BufferedImage buttonIcon = ImageIO.read(new File("img/button.png"));
button = new JButton(new ImageIcon(buttonIcon));
```

Comment: Try `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("img/button.png"));` or `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/img/button.png"));` if either of these fail then I would be checking the contents of the Jar file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read that file from inside your JAR use:

```
BufferedImage buttonIcon = ImageIO.read( getClass().getResourceAsStream("/classpath/to/my/file"));
```

Comment: Tried that and got this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues.

1. You need to put the file into the jar.
2. You need to use `getResourceAsStream(...)` to use the class loader to load from the jar.

To verify the image presence in the jar file, use the command `jar -tf jarfile.jar` and see if `button.png` is in the jar, where it is expected.  If it is not, look into altering your jar packaging.

As for the `getResourceAsStream(...)` there are many who have already offered how to do this properly.  Look to their answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
String imgPath = "img/button.png";
BufferedImage buffImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(imgPath));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path));
```

make sure the path doesn't contain the `src` folder (but keep the images in the actual folder)

```
path = "image.jpg";
```