# Generated .jar is unable to load some media files

Tags: java, swing, file, loading, embedded-resource

I built a java program using IntelliJ. This program loads media files like an image (.jpg) and audio (.wav).

When i run my project inside of the IDE, it works fine.
But when i generate a `.jar` file of my project, the image and audio files will not load.

- When i try to load the `.wav` audio file, i get a `FileNotFoundException`
- When i try to load the `.jpg` file, i get an `IIOException: Can't read the input file!`

I'm loading the image like this:

```
image = ImageIO.read(ImageScreen.class.getResourceAsStream("/quiz/resources/images/image_1.jpg"));`
```

When i inspect the top of the stack trace in the debugger, i can see: `javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unkown Source)`.

In other parts of my application, i'm able to load text files from a similar directory like this and it works in the .jar file too:

```
reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(
        WordScreen.class.getResourceAsStream(
            "/quiz/resources/words/wordlist.txt")));`
```

I only have one package called `quiz` in my project and i don't understand why this isn't working, as i am specifying an absolute path.

I've looked at other questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25028913/cant-read-input-file-when-compressed-as-a-jar), but in my opinion, i'm doing what is being suggested.

Comment: Do you see the `image_1.jpg` inside your JAR file in the right location?

Comment: `FileNotFoundException` with `wav` indicates that you are loading from the filesystem and not from the JAR. Please add the code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @RostislavKrasny Yes I've checked and the file is definitely there.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for your help. I have managed to find a fix for my problem.

I have changed this:

```
image = ImageIO.read(ImageScreen.class.getResourceAsStream("/quiz/resources/images/image_1.jpg"));
```

To this:

```
image = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/quiz/resources/images/image_1.jpg"));
```

I am now retrieving the `.wav` in the same way and it is working:

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/quiz/resources/audio/audio1.wav");
```

Answer (score 0):

try with getClassLoader()

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream...
```

Comment: That's one thing to try. Also, create an intermediate variable for the InputStream and check it for null.